# Why are Borel set's are measureable?

Tags: analysis

Let $ \mathcal{R}_{EG} $ the set off all elementary geometric set's and define $ \mathcal{B}^n:=\sigma(\mathcal{R}_{EG}) $ as the Borel-$ \sigma $-Algebra.

Let $ \lambda $ the elementary geometric content on $ \mathbb{R}^n $ and $ \lambda^* $ the outer measure on $ \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n) $ and $ \mathcal{A}_{\lambda^*} $ the set of all measureable set's in regard to $ \lambda^* $.

I don't see how to come to the fact $ \mathcal{B}^n\subseteq \mathcal{A}_{\lambda^*} $. I often hear this: "Because $ \mathcal{A}_{\lambda^*} $ is a Sigma-Algebra." and "$ \mathcal{R}_{EG}\subseteq \mathcal{A}_{\lambda^*} $". The second fact $ \mathcal{R}_{EG}\subseteq \mathcal{A}_{\lambda^*} $ is clear for me but not the first one. I know that $ \mathcal{A}_{\lambda^*} $ is a $ \sigma $-Algebra but then I don't know.

I tried to comprehent it like this: $ L\subseteq K\land L\subseteq M \Rightarrow K\subseteq M $ doesn't hold in general. But why if $ L=\mathcal{R}_{EG}, K=\mathcal{B}^n,M=\mathcal{A}_{\lambda^*}? $

Comment: What are *elementary geometric sets* and *elementary geometric content*?

Comment: Given any outer measure, the set of all Caratheodory measurable sets w.r.t that outer measure is a sigma algebra

Comment: A elementary geometric set describes a finite union of cuboid's of the form $ Q=I_1\times ...\times I_n \in \mathbb{R}^n $ and $  I_1,...,I_n $ are Intervalls from $ \mathbb{R} $. So for $ 
A\in \mathcal{R}_{EG} $ we get $ A=\bigcup_{k=1}^n Q_k $. The elementary geometric content $ \lambda $ is discribed by $ \lambda(Q):=\prod_{k=1}^n (b_k-a_k) $ and for mor general set's $ A\in \mathcal{R}_{EG} $ it is $ \lambda(A):=\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda(Q_k) $.

Comment: See [this](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch2.pdf) section $2.3$